# Создание программы на python и qt5, финальная часть

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

День добрый. Хотел бы задать такой вопрос:
написал я значит программу на python с использованием qt5 (открытие word документов), получилось что у меня есть main файл, файл с дизайном и ещё пару файлов  с картинками для настройки стиля, а также пару рабочих документов, всё это раскидал по папкам(в корне main и form,папка с картинками и папка с рабочими документами).
И теперь мне нужно всё это собрать и сделать единую программу, которая будет работать под Linux, но на машинах где нет ни питона не кюта.
Можете подсказать как сделать исполняемый файл или как перевести в бинарный код и запускать его. Может что почитать нужно, а то много уже прорыл но нигде конкретного ответа нет. Желательно чтобы была программа на ос виндовс , с возможностью выбора ос под которую будет сделана программа.

---

PS. На самом линуксе у меня нет рут прав, по этому все манипуляции могу производить только на винде с админкой.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: да, надо почитать https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/packaging-pyqt5-pyside2-applications-windows-pyinstaller/

Comment: Да ладно "нет питона", сейчас питон обычно везде есть, да по нескольку штук разных версий. Вот с qt, конечно, хуже. Лучше бы всё-таки поставить питон, в виде исполняемых файлов обычно как-то всё глючно.